# Is there a way to stop my images from overlapping my header/navbar without using z-index (which doesn't appear to work?)

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to set up a portfolio for a homework assignment, I've gotten everything working except I just realized that for some reason all the images that I'm using in place of my 'projects' are overlapping my fixed navbar/header.

I've tried toggling off all the styles affecting the images (and the header) with the Chrome Dev Console with no success, and I've messed around with z-index which also didn't work. The only things that are position: absolute are the labels (which are wrapped in position: relative div that does not include the images.) I've also tried googling it but have had little success. I'm probably just not explaining it well enough.

I'm not sure how to reproduce the issue, because I haven't been able to find the cause, so this might be a bit of a code dump.

All the code can also be found here: https://github.com/Munch-Z/Basic-Portfolio

And there's a link to a live Github Page at the top of the repo.

You may have to shrink your screen (vertically) to get the scroll-bar, and once you scroll down, the images will overlap.

This is my header HTML:

```html
 <header id="header">
                <div id="header-content">
                <h1 id="name">Zachary Murphy</h1>
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="about-link"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                        <li id="portfolio-link"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li id="contact-link"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            </header>

Header CSS:

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;
    border-color: #cccccc;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;

}

#header-content {
    max-width: 960px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    height: 90px;
}

header h1 {
background-color: #4aaaa5;
color: white;
padding: 25px 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
height: 100%;
font-family:  'Georgia', Times, Times New Roman, serif;
}

#nav-bar ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#nav-bar li {
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#nav-bar #about-link {
    border-left: none; 
}

Page HTML:
        <div id="hangman-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image"  src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Hangman game preview">
            <div id="hangman-text" class="text-wrapper">Hangman</div>
        </div>

        <div id="rpg-game-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="RPG game preview">
            <div id="rpg-text" class="text-wrapper">RPG Game</div>
        </div>

        <div id="trivia-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image"  src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="trivia game preview">
            <div id="trivia-text" class="text-wrapper">Trivia Game</div>
        </div>

        <div id="info-widget-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image"  src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Rutgers info widget preview">
            <div id="info-widget-text" class="text-wrapper">Rutgers Info Widget</div>
        </div>

        <div id="rock-paper-scissors-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image"  src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Rock paper scissors game preview">
            <div id="rock-paper-scissors-text" class="text-wrapper">Rock Paper Scissors</div>
        </div>

Page CSS:

#portfolio-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px;
    max-width: 480px;
    grid-gap: 25px 75px;
}

.portfolio-image {
    width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#hangman-div, #rpg-game-div, #trivia-div, #info-widget-div, #rock-paper-scissors-div {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

.text-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    color:  #ffffff;
    background-color: #4aaaa5;
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
}
```

I would like to be able to scroll on the page and have the images stay 'under' the header since I want to keep that fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar-header {background-color: #4AAAA5;}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS --> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aaronlilly.github.io/CDN/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <h1 id="name">Zachary Murphy</h1>
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="about-link"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                        <li id="portfolio-link"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li id="contact-link"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
             </div></nav>
             
             <div class="content-wrapper">
    <h2>Portfolio</h2>
    <div id="portfolio-wrapper">
        
        <div id="hangman-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Hangman game preview">
            <div id="hangman-text" class="text-wrapper">Hangman</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="rpg-game-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="RPG game preview">
            <div id="rpg-text" class="text-wrapper">RPG Game</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="trivia-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="trivia game preview">
            <div id="trivia-text" class="text-wrapper">Trivia Game</div>
        </div>

        <div id="info-widget-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Rutgers info widget preview">
            <div id="info-widget-text" class="text-wrapper">Rutgers Info Widget</div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="rock-paper-scissors-div">
            <img class="portfolio-image" src="assets/Images/placeholder.jpg" alt="Rock paper scissors game preview">
            <div id="rock-paper-scissors-text" class="text-wrapper">Rock Paper Scissors</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

there are a few things i did to solve this. I am not saying there isnt another way, but this is how i did it. #1, used bootstrap.  #2 you may need to override the "navbar" css to get your desired width/color etc. 
I used my own link to bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://aaronlilly.github.io/CDN/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

then this would be your "header"

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <h1 id="name">Zachary Murphy</h1>
                <nav id="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="about-link"><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                        <li id="portfolio-link"><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li id="contact-link"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
             </div></nav>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! Unfortunately, for this specific project, I'm not allowed to use Bootstrap. It has to be pure CSS. Sorry for not specifying with the question.

Comment: this may help - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_fixed_menu

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys! Turns out it was just a z-index issue and I was adjusting the z-index of the wrong elements. My bad.